# polymer slow svg click event handling

Tags: svg, polymer, snap.svg

I am working on an interactive svg polymer web component.  Recently, I swapped out simple block diagrams for high-fidelity svgs and immediately noticed much slower responses times to click events. The click handlers are attached to simple paths that overlay complicated svgs.  I have found in polymer.js (v0.5.4) that the mousedown function executes, a long delay of 100ms to 1000ms ensues, the polymer mouseup function executes, and then finally my click handler executes taking about 60ms.  I am wondering about the varying polymer delay between mousedown and mouseup as it's causing performance issues in my app.  I have thought it possibly related to the 300ms mobile click delay (http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away) but the delay is not consistent and I am running on desktops.  Typical delays appear to be around 160ms but variations over 500ms are especially hurtful to performance.  I have reproduced this on multiple machines within Chrome.  Any thoughts as to what is going on and how to fix it?

Here are some millisecond timings I collected where for example 516 is the polymer mousedown/mouseup delta and clickTime is the time to execute my handler.

```
polymer: 516  clickTime: 52 9% of total time
polymer: 137  clickTime: 51 27% of total time
polymer: 153  clickTime: 48 23% of total time
polymer: 136  clickTime: 47 25% of total time
polymer: 152  clickTime: 43 21% of total time
polymer: 442  clickTime: 44 9% of total time
polymer: 152  clickTime: 42 21% of total time
polymer: 150  clickTime: 41 21% of total time
polymer: 167  clickTime: 40 19% of total time
polymer: 147  clickTime: 41 21% of total time
polymer: 147  clickTime: 40 21% of total time
polymer: 148  clickTime: 42 21% of total time
polymer: 410  clickTime: 40 8% of total time
polymer: 132  clickTime: 48 26% of total time
polymer: 534  clickTime: 47 8% of total time
polymer: 537  clickTime: 47 8% of total time
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the issue includes Polymer? What happens if you take your SVG and use bare DOM events, do you still see the delay? i.e. document.querySelector('svg line').addEventListener(...)

Comment: Yes, I can run it outside of Polymer w/o issue - my click handler runs immediately.  From Chrome's profiler I noticed this huge delay between the polymer mousedown and mouseup before my handler ran.